# Use the same javascript for multiple images on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of pairs of images that I want to place on the same page. I want to be able to toggle between each pair of images using the same external javascript code, i.e. without have to repeat the code for each item.

This code below works perfectly for toggling between one pair of images using data attributes but how would I go about using the same code again for a different pair of images on the same page?

````
<html>

<head>
    
<div id='urls' data-image1='https://www.dropbox.com/s/79pypzinnvyk36u/apple.jpg?raw=1' data-image2='https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zmsaqhal9ettus/banana.jpg?raw=1'></div>

<script>
    
    var images = document.getElementById('urls');
        var src1 = images.getAttribute('data-image1');
        var src2 = images.getAttribute('data-image2');
    
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == src2)
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = src1;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = src2;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
    
    <body>
        <p>
        <img alt="" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/79pypzinnvyk36u/apple.jpg?raw=1" 
            style="width: 100%; max-width:800px; height: auto; border: 0;" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
        </p>
    </body>


</html>```
````

Comment: Use parameters in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the parameters I needed in the onClick function.

````
<html>

<head>
    

<script>
    
    
    function changeImage(src1, src2,imgID) {

        if (document.getElementById(imgID).src == src2)
        {
            document.getElementById(imgID).src = src1;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById(imgID).src = src2;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
    
    <body>
        <p>
        <img alt="" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/79pypzinnvyk36u/apple.jpg?raw=1" 
            style="width: 100%; max-width:800px; height: auto; border: 0;" id="appleBanana" onclick="changeImage('https://www.dropbox.com/s/79pypzinnvyk36u/apple.jpg?raw=1','https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zmsaqhal9ettus/banana.jpg?raw=1','appleBanana' )" />
        </p>
        
                <p>
        <img alt="" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5khsr21jvec69n/tomato.jpg?raw=1" 
            style="width: 100%; max-width:800px; height: auto; border: 0;" id="tomatoCucumber" onclick="changeImage('https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5khsr21jvec69n/tomato.jpg?raw=1','https://www.dropbox.com/s/zejo8o19c8ropco/cucumber.jpg?raw=1','tomatoCucumber')" />
        </p>
        
    </body>


</html>```
````

Answer (score 4):

Your current function only targets a specific image element. But you can get access to the  tag that fired the element in the event handler callbacks if you review these MDN docs: [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

I prefer the addEventListener syntax but you can also pass in 'this' in your onClick function call and then access the event object in your changeImage() function to get your toggle behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @Dan P, this is very useful information and I’m trying hard to wrap my newbie brain around it. Do you think you show me some example code that illustrates what you’re talking about? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok! I finally figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah glad to hear you got it.

For anyone else looking at this question the two ways I described can be done as:


1. In the <img> tag onclick attribute pass in "this" so it'll look like: <img ... onClick="changeImage(this)" ... /> where I truncated all the other attributes as ellipses. Then in the function the passed in value (this) has the current target property.


2. Use event listeners so remove onClick and add it via just pure javascript.


So get the imgTag with your favourite selector. Then add event listeners, and the event object is passed in the callback.